# Powershell, how to compare user input

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-v5.0

I'm making a "shortcut" PS1 script to update a domain user's password. I'd like to prompt the user for the new password twice without showing the password on screen. When I use `$Text1=Read-Host ; $Text2=Read-Host ; $Text1 -eq $Text2` with the same input - '1' for example - the output of that one-liner is "True". However,

```
$Text1=Read-Host -AsSecureString ; $Text2=Read-Host -AsSecureString ; $Text1 -eq $Text2
```

and

```
$Text1=Read-Host -AsSecureString ; $Text2=Read-Host -AsSecureString ; (ConvertFrom-SecureString $Text1) -eq (ConvertFrom-SecureString $Text2)
```

return False.

The script as it is now, without prompting twice and comparing user inputs, is below and it works to reset a user's password.

```
$UserName = Read-Host "User name "
$NewPass = Read-Host -AsSecureString
Set-ADAccountPassword `
    -NewPassword $NewPass `
    -Verbose `
    -Identity ( (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '$UserName'").DistinguishedName )
$NewPass.Dispose()
```

[image: Working PS1 script to reset domain user's password]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4546.working-with-passwords-secure-strings-and-credentials-in-windows-powershell.aspx), you have to "decrypt" the secureString with the following method:

```
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($text1)
$PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

First, this converts the secure string to "Basic String" data type (BSTR), and from that back to a readable string. This will give you the plain text password the user entered. You could for example put this in a small function that you can call for both passwords like this:

```
 function Decrypt-Password ($secureString){
   $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
   $PlainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
   return $PlainPassword
  }

$Text1=Read-Host -AsSecureString
$Text2=Read-Host -AsSecureString    
(Decrypt-Password -secureString $text1) -eq (Decrypt-Password -secureString $text2)
```

This will work like expected.

You could also create a function that will directly compare two given SecureStrings, but I will leave the exact implementation up to you.